# What does maven auto build do exactly?

Tags: maven-2

When I change some code I can see this pop into the console 'Maven Builder: AUTO_BUILD'. I would have expected my target folder to have been updated(re-built) but this does not seem to be the case.

Thanks,
Daniel.

Comment: Maven itself does not autobuild.  Are you running inside an IDE of some sort?  Perhaps NetBeans or Eclipse?  Those will auto build the project by default anytime you save changes to a source file.

Comment: Thanks John, I am using Eclipse kepler with JBoss as our app server. We just moved from weblogic and Eclipse galileo but nothing seems to be building at the moment...

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have installed the 'Maven Integration for Eclipse plugin' and switched on the Maven Project Builder in the builders for my projects. I have multiple maven projects with lots of dependencies in a hierarchical format. If I change anything at the moment I seem to have to do a build from the command line for changes to be picked up by dependent projects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maven Auto-Build step of the Maven Eclipse Plugin essentially executes the equivalent of `mvn compile`.  It does not execute a clean or any lifecycle phases beyond compile.  This means that a Maven Auto-Build will not generate any of the JAR files that the Maven project might be configured to generate.

Comment: Thanks John, I can see it updating the class files under the target folder now